# sqlalchemy reflected table to orm?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I reflected an existing sqlalchemy table using:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
db_engine = sa.create_engine('postgres+psycopq2://postgres:pwrd@localhost/test')
meta = sa.MetaData()
records = sa.Table('records', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=db_engine)
```

now when I try to add data into it via

```
from sqlalchemy.orm insert sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)
session = Session()

new_record = records(Col1='sdf', Col2='sdsfdadf')
session.add(new_record)
session.commit()
```

I get an error with

```
TypeError: 'Table' object is not callable
```

isn't a reflected table usable in the same way that a declared table is?

Comment: No, you'd issue insert statements in case of Core `Table`. Have a look at the related tutorial: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#insert-expressions. In addition by "declared table" you probably mean a Declarative model class, which creates a `Table` based on the class definition, accessible as `MyModel.__table__`, and maps said table to the class.

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare your own model class first, as Ilja Everilä suggested:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
class Records(Base):
    __table__ = sa.Table('records', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=db_engine)
```

Then you may use the new model class `Records` to operate database:

```
new_record = Records(Col1='sdf', Col2='sdsfdadf')
session.add(new_record)
session.commit()
```